# Problem in android splash screen ---- stretched

Tags: android, splash-screen, stretch

Tried everything to fix it didn't find any solution Help me out please and I'm a unexperienced person

[Splash screen stretched](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zz78Y.jpg)

Comment: Share your code first.

Answer (score 0):

Please share the code of your Splash Screen's xml. Seems like you're using

```
android:layout_width=match_parent
```

for your Splash image.

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:opacity="opaque">
    <!-- The background color, preferably the same as your normal theme -->
    <item android:drawable="?colorSurface" />
    <!-- Your product logo - 288px x 288px color version of your app icon -->
    <item android:bottom="@dimen/splash_logo_bottom">
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/app_splash_screen_picture"
            android:tileMode="disabled" />
    </item>
</layer-list>`